# Como ler um arquivo excel em uma aplicação de console em c#?

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel

Galera,estou tentando ler uns dados de uma tabela do excel em c#,meu codigo está assim:

```
            string resp;
            string rota= "D:/Users/e608871/documents/visual studio 2010/Projects/CEMIGID/CEMIGID/CEMIGID.xlsx";
            var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(rota);
            var res = (from row in excel.Worksheet("Sheet1")
                       let item = new Program
                       {

                           ID = row[0].Cast<string>(),
                           diretorio = row[1].Cast<string>()
                       }
                       select item).ToList();
            excel.Dispose();
            foreach (var item in res)
            {
                resp = item.ID;
            }
```

mas ele não lê,apenas abre o console e não mostra nada

Comment: É porque não tem nenhum  `Console.WriteLine()` ai. O que você queria que ele mostrasse?

Comment: é pq eu to debugando e no debug ele não está pegando os valores

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que a variável `res` possua valor, você pode exibi-los usando o método WriteLine do Console (considerando que sua aplicação seja de Console).

```
foreach (var item in res)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.ID);
}
```

Dentro do foreach você está atribuindo `resp = item.ID` sabe que está sempre sobrescrevendo o valor da váriavel `resp`, certo?